# how to check if user is authenticated with passport (get user from token using laravel-passport)

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite

I am using Passport to log in users to a Laravel API endpoint, users get authenticated using their social accounts (google, facebook) using laravel-socialite package.

the workflow of logging users in and out works perfectly (generating tokens...Etc). The problem is I have a controller that should return data based on whether there is a user logged in or not.

I do intercept the Bearer token from the HTTP request but I couldn't get the user using the token (I would use DB facade to select the user based on the token but I am actually looking whether there is a more clean way already implemented in Passport)

I also don't want to use auth:api middleware as the controller should work and return data even if no user is logged in.

this is the api route:

```php
Route::get("/articles/{tag?}", "ArticleController@get_tagged");
```

this is the logic I want the controller to have

```php
public function get_tagged($tag = "", Request $request)
{
    if ($request->header("Authorization"))
        // return data related to the user
    else
        // return general data
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you set your api guard to passport, you can simply call `if (Auth::guard('api')->check())` to check for an authenticated user:

```php
public function get_tagged($tag = "", Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::guard('api')->check()) {
        // Here you have access to $request->user() method that
        // contains the model of the currently authenticated user.
        //
        // Note that this method should only work if you call it
        // after an Auth::check(), because the user is set in the
        // request object by the auth component after a successful
        // authentication check/retrival
        return response()->json($request->user());
    }

    // alternative method
    if (($user = Auth::user()) !== null) {
        // Here you have your authenticated user model
        return response()->json($user);
    }

    // return general data
    return response('Unauthenticated user');
}
```

This would trigger the Laravel authentication checks in the same way as auth:api guard, but won't redirect the user away. In fact, the redirection is done by the `Authenticate` middleware (stored in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php`) upon the failure of the authentication checking.

Beware that if you don't specify the guard to use, Laravel will use the default guard setting in the `config/auth.php` file (usually set to web on a fresh Laravel installation).

If you prefer to stick with the Auth facade/class you can as well use `Auth::guard('api')->user()` instead or the request object.

Answer (score 3):

thanks to @mdexp answer

In my case I can resolve my problem with using

```
if (Auth::guard('api')->check()) {
    $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
}
```

In my controller.